# List Agent real names from Get-CsCallQueue cmdlet

Tags: powershell-remoting

I run the Get-CsCallQueue | Select-Object -Property Name,Agents cmdlet, but I want to see the real names of the agents. Instead I get something like hashes(?).

How can I see the names?

```
Get-CsCallQueue | Select-Object -Property Name,Agents

Name             Agents                                                                                                                                                                                    
----             ------                                                                                                                                                                                    
CQ1         {adfe5681-ebc8-xxx-xxxx-........, OptIn}      
CQ2         {adfe5681-ebc8-xxx-xxxx-......., OptIn}      
CQ3         {baae77b8-5ace-xxx-xxxx-......, OptOut}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this Skype for Business Online (SFBO) or on-prem? You need to match up the agent GUID with the agent name. You'll need to use different cmdlets depending on your answer. Here's an example of how to do this using SFBO:

```
$queue = get-cscallqueue -NameFilter "<queue name here>"
$agents = $queue.agents
foreach ($agent in $agents) {
    $user = $agent.ObjectId | Get-CsOnlineUser
    $agent | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $user.alias 
   } 
 $agents|Select Name,OptIn
```

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Jason, you rock, thank you so much!
It works.

Cheers,
Toni

Answer (score 0):

Working on this with a Script that does the heavy lifting for you.

Module is [Teamsfunctions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/TeamsFunctions/) on PSgallery.

The command is `Get-TeamsCallQueue`. I have surfaced all friendly names for Get/New/Set/Remove for CallQueues (I still need to finish testing on them, so handle with care :), should be finished in the coming weeks)

There is also `Find-AzureAdUser` in my module so that you can get the Object by feeding it the UPN instead of the ObjectID.
Hope that helps :)